# How to align 5 boxes with flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

I need help with aligning 5 boxes according to the wireframe preview at:
https://projekty.freshynek.cz/images/hp-wireframe.png

[image]

Box No. 1 should take 50% width, the others only 25% of the container width sitting at the right of the big box.

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 1170px;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col-first {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
}

.big {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.col-second {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
}

.two,
.three,
.four,
.five {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.three {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="col-first">

    <div class="big">
      <div class="text">1. big</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- .col-first -->

  <div class="col-second">

    <div class="two">
      <p>2. small</p>
    </div>

    <div class="three">
      <p>3. small</p>
    </div>

    <div class="four">
      <p>4. small</p>
    </div>

    <div class="five">
      <p>5. small</p>
    </div>

  </div><!-- .col-first -->

</div><!-- .flex-container -->
```

I tried to use flexbox to align all 5 boxes, but cannot find the right way. Thank you for any help.

Comment: You shoud make the second column a flex container: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add following css properties to `.col-second` class.

1. `display: flex` - This is necessary so that your `4 turquoise` boxes can be controlled using flexbox. After applying `display:flex` to `.col-second`, it will act as parent container for these boxes.
2. `flex-wrap: wrap` - This is necessary so that when the items (total) exceed the width of parent, they shift to next line. Without this your `4 turquoise` boxes will remain in a single row rather than in two rows. `flex-wrap` will only work if you have `display:flex` on the same item.

Working snippet attached.

[More on flex-wrap here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/)

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 1170px;
  display: flex;
}

.text {
  margin: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col-first {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
}

.big {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.col-second {
  width: 50%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.two,
.three,
.four,
.five {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.three {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">

  <div class="col-first">

    <div class="big">
      <div class="text">1. big</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- .col-first -->

  <div class="col-second">

    <div class="two">
      <p>2. small</p>
    </div>

    <div class="three">
      <p>3. small</p>
    </div>

    <div class="four">
      <p>4. small</p>
    </div>

    <div class="five">
      <p>5. small</p>
    </div>

  </div><!-- .col-first -->

</div><!-- .flex-container -->
```

Comment: Thank you for an excellent explanation. Now it works like a charm 

Comment: @Freshynek Can you please accept my answer then  :).